# Twitter Bootstrap Nav Menu won't expand under small resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using an off-the-shelf theme.  When I shrink the viewport width to something small (say 400 px wide), I can't expand the navigation menu.

I tried the theme and it works:

https://genesisui.com/demo/real/bootstrap3/

However, my site does not:

http://recruitersight.com

I've tried the suggestions in this post: [nav menu won't expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886260/nav-menu-wont-expand)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In its current form, your question is off-topic on [SO]. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to understand why and what options you have for improving it. Besides, if it's a paid theme and you haven't modified it, you should be asking this on their support forum.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are using the wrong version of JQuery, you are using 3.2.1 which isn't compatible with bootstrap, you need JQuery 2.x.

Try version 2.2.4 from here http://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Could you quote any credible source on *"jQuery 3.2.1 isn't compatible with bootstrap"*, please? Bootstrap supports jQuery 3.x since July 25th, 2016, according to [themselves](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2016/07/25/bootstrap-3-3-7-released/), which is a credible source in my book.

Comment: My source is another stack overflow post. I had this issue a while back and changing the JQuery version fixed it. Thanks for the update though I have been using 2.x for all my sites....